# Correct way to handle copy/paste from a View into a GraphicalEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

We're developing an application in which we handle local copy/pastes within the diagram by using the extension point `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.clipboard.core.clipboardSupport`

Copy/Paste events of resources in views are handled using a handler with the commandId `org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy/paste`

My question is , what's the correct way of handling copy/paste events between the diagram (or any GraphicalEditor for that matter) and other views in the application?

Currently, I was managed to solve it programatically, putting this code in the DiagramEditor initialization method:

```
IActionBars actionBars = site.getActionBars();
EditPartViewer diagramGraphicalViewer = getDiagramGraphicalViewer();
actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(GEFActionConstants.PASTE, new PasteMethodNodeAction(clipboard,diagramGraphicalViewer));
```

But it overrides the other paste listeners of the Editor and generally interrupts our design.

Any ideas will be welcome :-)